# Extract all numbers from a text file and store them in another file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file which have lots of lines. I want to extract all the numbers from that file. 
File contains text and number and each line contains only one number. 
How can i do it using sed or awk in bash script?

i tried

```
#! /bin/bash
sed 's/\([0-9.0-9]*\).*/\1/' <myfile.txt >output.txt
```

but this didn't worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grep can handle this:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+' myfile.txt
```

`-o` tells to print only the matches and `[0-9\.]+` is a regular expression to match numbers.

To put all numbers on one line and save them in output.txt:

```
echo $(grep -Eo '[0-9\.]+' myfile.txt) >output.txt
```

Text files should normally end with a newline characters.  The use of `echo` above assures that this happens.

#### Non-GNU grep:

If your grep does not support the `-o` flag, try:

```
echo $(tr ' ' '\n' <myfile.txt | grep -E '[0-9\.]+') >output.txt
```

This uses `tr` to replace all spaces with newlines (so each number appears separately on a line) and then uses `grep` to search for numbers.

Comment: i am putting output in out.txt by >. but this is keeping output in different lines. I want to keep all output in same line with a space

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -sc '0-9.' ' ' "$file"
```

Will transform every string of non-digit-or-period characters into a single space.

Comment: This is good, but leaves the text.  I think the desired approach is: `tr -dc '[:digit:]\n'` or `tr -dc '0-9\n'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell What do you mean by *leaves the text*? OP said (in his comment to John1024's answer) he wants all output on a single line.

Comment: I misunderstood your solution, which is brilliant.  I should have actually executed it first!  If I could upvote again I would.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Bash:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ [0-9\.]+ ]]; then
        echo $BASH_REMATCH
    fi
done <myfile.txt >output.txt
```